# How to get value of child tag of a button tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get src value from html button when user clicks it.

```
<button type="button" value="95" id="load" onclick="functionName(this.src,this.value);">
    <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon-small.png">
    <span>Welcome</span>
</button>
```

Successfully getting value from `this.value` but `this.src` is not giving any value.

Comment: `this` would not point to the `img` element. Use `this.querySelector('img').src` instead.

Comment: Because `button` does not have the property `src`??!! It's children image has the property: please try something like that: `this.children[0].src`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is referring to the button which doesn't have the `src` attribute. Image inside the button has the `src` attribute.

You can pass `this` to your function and access `src` of the image using `button.children[0].src` or `button.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src`

```js
function functionName(button, value) {
  let src1 = button.children[0].src;
  let src2 = button.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
  console.log(src1, src2, value);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="95" id="load" onclick="functionName(this,this.value);">
  <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon-small.png">
  <span>Welcome</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, when u pass the **this** to the function, the **this** is your button, or in your case the this.value is the attribute value of your button and the this.src the value of your button attribute src, and you dont have the button src attribute

What can you do?:

- Pass the only the param this to your function and over there, get the value of your attribute value.
- Inside your function, through the this, get the children image and get it attribute src

Is something like this:

```js
function functionName(button) {
  var buttonValue = button.value;
  var imageSrc = button.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="95" id="load" onclick="functionName(this);">
  <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon-small.png">
  <span>Welcome</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `querySelector` to target the image source

**Example:**

```js
function functionName(button) {
  var src = button.querySelector("img").src;
  console.log(src);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="95" id="load" onclick="functionName(this);">
    <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon-small.png">
    <span>Welcome</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context `this` & use `children` method.The button does not have `src` property,it belongs to the `img` tag, so `children` will give array of children.

```js
function functionName(elem) {
  //elem will be button itself
  var _childImg = elem.children[0].src
  console.log(_childImg, elem.value)
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="95" id="load" onclick="functionName(this);">
                        <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon-small.png">
                        <span>Welcome</span>

    </button>
```

Comment: `this` === `document.getElementById(this.id)`.  Why dig into the element to find its id so you can look up the element by id when you have the element to start with?

Comment: @James I agree, my bad i overlooked that